# lifecycleScope.launchWhen*** deprecated, what's an alternative?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

Before we could use:

```
lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    // Do something async
}
```

But now it's deprecated.

```
lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycleOwner.whenStarted { 
        // Do something async
    }
}
```

This one is also deprecated

I found another way but it looks ugly:

```
lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycleOwner.withStarted { // the block is not suspended...
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch { 
            // Do something async
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. such code only executes once, please don't suggest me to use `repeatOnLifecycle` which will be called every time such state is triggered

Comment: `withStarted` is fine, just leave the lambda empty and proceed to write your suspending code below it. But do be aware of caveats of it: once the suspension and state check passes, your suspending code will keep running until lifecycle is destroyed eg. even when lifecycle becomes paused.

Comment: Similar to what @Pawel stated, here's an answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75885233/6819340

Comment: As `repeatOnLifecycle` does the job, but there is an extension function called flowWithLifecycle that wraps some of the boilerplate code for us. Check a detailed explain by Manuel Vivo here https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleCoroutineScope#launchWhenStarted(kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)), you should stop using `launchWhenStarted` due to "wasted resources," and instead replace such call with "`repeatOnLifecycle` to run the block whenever the Lifecycle state is at least `Lifecycle.State.STARTED`."

While you asked not to be given this alternative, I would argue that following Google's recommendations is usually the best approach.  If you don't want to get called every time the state changes, as you say, then I would recommend you check the `Lifecycle.State` before executing your code, and only doing so for the state(s) that you actually want your code to cover.

Comment: because yeah, there are so many cases could be in different categories of apps, it can't be just `repeatOnLifecycle` (for ordinary client servers apps with typical data in viewmodel from backend). I just want to ensure that some callbacks after, e.g. permissions were granted, camera2 open/preview started (cameraX with lifecycle is still don't cover all features of camera2) or any other handle cases are called for UI a specific state and only once

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is new easy method to do that like this

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            collect {
                onChange(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: which is called every time there is `STARTED` event. read my question again